# How to implement push on a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I am looking for help implementing push stack on this linked list. Some tips would be appreciated :)

The program runs properly, I am just looking how to add a push statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackList {
    LinkedListBasic stackList = new LinkedListBasic();

    // Adds new elements to the top of the stack
    public void push(int data){

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    StackList newStackList = new StackList();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true){
        int data = input.nextInt();
        if(data == -1) break;
        newStackList.push(data);
    }


public class Node{
    int data;
    Node next;

    public Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
        next =  null;
}
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a question where we can't help you without doing the work for you entirely. What exactly are you confused about?

Answer (score 0):

To push a new element onto the top of the linked list, you must have access to the head (first element) of the linked list and do three things:

1. Create a new node with the appropriate data
2. Set the new node's `next` field to the head of the linked list
3. Set the linked list's head to be the new node

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are maintaining a head node.

```
public void push(int data) {
       if(head == null) {
         Node node = new Node(data);
         head = node;
       }else {
         Node node = new Node(data);
         node.next = head;
         head = node;
      }
}
```